# Built ASP.NET Application in Visual Studio - How Move it to IIS Express?

Tags: asp.net, iis, deployment

Been scouring web, this seems like a very simple thing to do...I have done a lot of PHP deployments, but ASP.NET is killing me...

I built ASP.NET app in Visual Studio. I can run it from the IIS Express button. Not sure what it does, sticks in on a new port. Anyway, I want to take this app and put it under IIS Express so I can run it just from localhost in browser. I know how to Publish, and can create the publish folder under bin. All very simple. But, in the directions, it says to copy all those files to the web site - I've done that, into the document root. But there is no htm, html, .aspx, etc, etc file. How do I run this app that I copied over?

For example, my app is HelloWorld. There are EXE, DLL, PDB, JSON, and other files in the publish folder. There is a wwwroot folder with CSS and other stuff. What do I need to do to put this under IIS Express and run it as /localhost/HelloWorld or whatever?

I am missing something very elementary here. I feel stupid, because I've done some very complex sites with PHP, JS, MySQL, etc, etc...

Thanks...

Comment: In day 1 you must learn "ASP.NET" vs. "ASP.NET Core", as well as "IIS Express" vs. IIS before moving on. Try to use a search engine to dig further, and then clean up your question above because it currently shows all kinds of ambiguity what you used exactly. In case you are actually working on ASP.NET Core with IIS Express and VS, to publish to IIS you just need to follow https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Are you sure you want to use IIS Express? You can use `appcmd` (should be at `C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\appcmd.exe`) to define the site (it will add configuration to your `%userprofile%\Documents\IISExpress\config` file) and then launch the site with `C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe`. You'll want to read the documentation for each of those commands, as there's a number of options you might need to pass to each of those executables, for example to define the site, create application pools, set the content root etc. You're really better off using IIS (not IIS Express)

Comment: Sorry I was ambiguous. It is IIS Express, and built with ASP.NET Core. Just followed MS tutorials. Didn't realize the world turned upside down, no more index.html, etc files. I just need to brush up on my ASP (did ASP many years ago). I think I will play with ASP with ,NET framework instead.

Comment: Just because you don't have an index.html file isn't really a problem. Just learn about routing. ASP.NET Core is what any new .NET based web application should use - don't learn the old stuff if you don't have a specific reason to. It's going to die out (rightfully so).

Answer (score 0):

No static files such as HTML is a normal phenomenon in AspNet Core application hosting files. Just place all build output files into the root directory of the website. Also, please ensure that the Asp.Net Core hosting bundle has been installed on the webserver.
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/thank-you/runtime-aspnetcore-3.1.6-windows-hosting-bundle-installer
In addition, IIS Express just a simplified version of the webserver, in order to facilitate Visual Studio debugging web application. try to enable the IIS standard web server in windows.
[image]
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/install/installing-iis-7/installing-iis-on-windows-vista-and-windows-7
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.